# Simplest way to read in a file of type 'file' into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

I am trying to read in files of type 'File' on Windows into pandas DataFrames. The files have columns of data that are separated by N number of spaces and have a variable number of columns. For instance, here are two examples of the Files with some data.

File1

```
Bob              Smith   1
Angelina          Ross   2
```

File2

```
Mars      Red                     Planet         Small
Sun    Yellow                       Star           Big
```

What's the easiest way to read in those two files above to result in dataframes? **These files are not .csv files. They have no extension and I open them via notepad++**

Comment: file type 'file' means that format in unknown or missing https://fileinfo.com/extension/file what program are you opening them in?

Comment: @Cam opening them with notepad++

Comment: Can you just rename as .csv or .txt maybe? Please take a copy of the files before trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these seem to be plain text files, you can read them into a dataframe with `read_csv` and `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file2', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

Result:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mars | Red | Planet | Small |
| 1 | Sun | Yellow | Star | Big |

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
list = dataframe["column"].tolist()

This code reads dataframe and creates a list of what is in column
You should work with pandas series(column)
Output:
['1', '2', '3', '4']

Comment: these are not .csv files, they have no extension and default to 'File' on Windows 10

Comment: import pandas as pd
text = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep = " ", header = None)